# I'm adding a link on ui page but it getting error it's not added

Tags: xhtml

```xml
<a class="button" target=_remotePage" href=" here give a link but it's getting error on ui page">
Daily unit values
</a>
```

Comment: "it's getting error" — and the error message says what?

Comment: You tagged this [tag:xhtml] - are you really using XHTML? It's extremely rare these days.

Comment: The error  application has occured.

Answer (score -1):

You have malformed HTML code, try this:

```
<a class="button" target="_blank" href="#">my link</a>
```

Valid options for target are:

- _blank
- _self
- _parent
- _top
- *framename*

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: I tried this one also but no result